# Mathematical characterization of gravitational geons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differential-equations

I've edited a closed-related question on MathOverflow, the post with idenfier **430449**, this [*post.*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430449/mathematical-characterization-of-gravitational-geons-as-reference-request-and-t)

I hope that the following post is suitable for the site, in other case please add your feedback in comments that I can to delete the post tomorrow. I've asked on Meta of the site MathOverlow a related question since I'm interested in gravitational geons. I need your help to know if one can to state a mathematical characterization of gravitational geons, by means of equations. The post is [*Asking if a post about a mathematical characterization of gravitational geons can be potentially interesting for the main site MathOverflow*](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5432/asking-if-a-post-about-a-mathematical-characterization-of-gravitational-geons-ca) edited few days ago.

Gravitational geons is an hypothetical object in theoretical physics. I add as general reference that Wikipedia has the article [*Geon (physics).*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics))

> **Question.** I need your help to know what are a set of equations (or a mathematical characterization) that characterizes a gravitational geon. From  your answer I could to expand it asking about the properties of solutions on MathOverflow. **Many thanks.**

From a conversation in one of the rooms of your chat, if I refer well I professor tell me that to find an analytic solution for gravitional geons is very difficult, and that are a hypothetical object.

If the answer is explicit in the literature please answer my question as a reference request, adding the article.

Comment: I'm mathematician but I'm not a professional, in the past as student I know several courses of ordinary/partial differential equations, differential geometry and geometry of varieties, a course of physics. If you can to improve the choice of tags that I did please help me. On the other hand I emphasize that if the post isn't suitable for the site Physics Stack Exchange there is no problem because I can to delete it tomorrow (at the morning).

Comment: As is implicit in my last comment I know Einstein field euation and principles of quantum mechanics from a point of view of dissemination of science from books. I'm asking about a set of equations or conditions (that you know that are a characterization of gravitational geons). I know that it is an hypothetical object, but if I refer well these were studied by Wheeler who was a great physicist. Today thanks to experimental and theoretical physicists, we know that black holes are out there, as well as on paper as solutions of equations (the cost of knowledge is very great).

Comment: The article in wiki gives you the quote to  Brill–Hartle , so you should first try thhere article. since geons are very speculative, I doubt, that you find a mathematical characterization .

Comment: Many thanks @trula if I can to access to the article I will try it. In my view even if an object is very speculative it deserves to be described. Language symbols and equations are necessary for scientists to study the veracity of existence an object. I've upvoted your feedback.

Comment: On arXiv there is the article *Gravitational Geons Revisited*, by 
Paul R. Anderson and  Dieter R. Brill (last revised 3 Sep 1997) @trula

Comment: [Try this collection of papers on arXiv.](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=geon&searchtype=abstract&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50)

Comment: You're very friendly, many thanks when I can I take a look of the articles @CameronWilliams